# Cron expression validator for Apache Quartz

Tags: java, datetime, validation

Not too long ago, I had to create a cron expression for a route in Apache Camel. I had a bit of a struggle to find the right expression. So I made a small program to output the n next valid dates returned by the expression. I planned to add more feature like instead of making a blind `Sysout`, you could create a file with your dates.

In my application, a cron expression correspond to the definition of this [class](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html). It's use to fire an event for a [Camel route](http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html). You will set a Quartz endpoint to your route and use a cron expression to express at which interval it should start. Some example :

> 0 0/5 12-18 ? * MON-FRI

This cron expression translated to a more human format would be : every five minutes starting at 12pm (noon) to 6pm on weekdays. (this cron is taken from the quartz documentation).

For this particular cron, my program (with an `numberOfdates` set to 5) would output :

> Fri Sep 19 12:05:00 EDT 2014
>   Fri Sep 19 12:10:00 EDT 2014
>   Fri Sep 19 12:15:00 EDT 2014
>   Fri Sep 19 12:20:00 EDT 2014
>   Fri Sep 19 12:25:00 EDT 2014

The application is really basic. I take two arguments, the cron expression and the numbers of date you want outputted.

Feel free to cover any aspect. I had particular problem with the naming of my classes and variables. There isn't much code at the moment, but my naming and the way I verify arguments worry me a bit.

It's a public repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/marcandregirard/cronTester)

CronTester

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class CronTester {

    /**
     * The application take two arguments : 
     * The first argument is the cron expression surrounded by " : "* * * * * *"
     * The second argument is the number of dates you want to verify. It's a simple Integer.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You should only provide 2 arguments. \"[cronExpression]\" [numberOfDates]");
        } else if (args.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You need to provide 2 arguments in the following form : \"[cronExpression]\" [numberOfDates]");
        }

        final String expression = args[0];
        final int numberOfDates;

        try {
            numberOfDates = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The second argument need to be a valid integer.");
        }

        final CronDateCreator dateCreator = new CronDateCreator(expression);
        List<Date> result = dateCreator.createValidTimeDatesFromNow(numberOfDates);

        for(Date expected : result) {
            System.out.println(expected);
        }

    }

}
```

CronDateCreator

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.quartz.CronExpression;

public class CronDateCreator {

    private CronExpression cron;

    public CronDateCreator(String cronExpressionRaw) {
        try {
            this.cron = new CronExpression(cronExpressionRaw);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The cron expression supplied is not a valid cron expression.",e);
        }
    }

    public List<Date> createValidTimeDates(Date startingDate, int numberOfDates) { 
        Date nextValidDate = cron.getNextValidTimeAfter(startingDate);
        List<Date> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDates; i++) {
            results.add(nextValidDate);
            nextValidDate = cron.getNextValidTimeAfter(nextValidDate);
        }

        return results;
    }

    public List<Date> createValidTimeDatesFromNow(int numberOfDates) {
        return createValidTimeDates(new Date(), numberOfDates);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you running on Java 8, or are you restricted to <= Java7?

Comment: No restriction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of overall hierarchy here, the CronTester class is just 'fluff' and does not do anything except provide an main method. The interesting class is: `CronDateCreator`.

`CronDateCreator` is a very lightweight class. It essentially does nothing that requires it to be a class... it wraps a `String` value in a `CronExpression`, is that `CronExpression` reused for anything?

It strikes me that the standard use-case for this class would be:

```
CronDateCreator cdc = new CronDateCreator(input);
List<Date> dates = cdc.createValidTimeDatesFromNow(numberOfDates);
```

and then the `cdc` will be forgotten.

Is this a case of where a static method is maybe all you need?

Something like:

```
public static List<Date> createValidTimeDatesFromNow(String expression, int numberOfDates) {
    ....
}
```

Just a thought...

### Date

Now, about the Date return values.

`Date` is a much maligned class in Java. It has so many nuances, issues, and tweaks that it was initially 'forked' and rewritten as `JodaTime` in an open source library, then, in Java8, they have pulled the best from JodaTime, and incorporated some other compatibility and functionality changes, and created the new `java.time.*` package.

Any code written to support Java8 or newer should essentially abandon `Date`, and work with [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)  instead.

You should use your class/static methods to translate the Dates back to Instants, and go from there.

### Actual code:

Your method here could be neatened up a lot:

> ```
> public List<Date> createValidTimeDates(Date startingDate, int numberOfDates) { 
>     Date nextValidDate = cron.getNextValidTimeAfter(startingDate);
>     List<Date> results = new ArrayList<>();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDates; i++) {
>         results.add(nextValidDate);
>         nextValidDate = cron.getNextValidTimeAfter(nextValidDate);
>     }
>
>     return results;
> }
> ```

For a start, you know how large the ArrayList will be, so set the size on the constructor:

```
List<Date> results = new ArrayList<>(numberOfDates);
```

Then, your loop logic is off... how about the following?:

```
public List<Date> createValidTimeDates(Date startingDate, final int numberOfDates) { 
    List<Date> results = new ArrayList<>(numberOfDates);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDates; i++) {
        startingDate = cron.getNextValidTimeAfter(startingDate);
        results.add(startingDate);
    }        
    return results;
}
```

Comment: At first everything was in the same class, so I moved the cron method into his own class. I guess it's because at that time I was thinking in adding more functionality. I'll move from `Date`, Java 8 is not something we're working with at work, so I'm a bit "late" with all the new stuff.

Comment: @Marc-Andre And so am I, but I can repeat the recommendation against `Date`. It's maybe the worst class ever. There's an official [backport of JDK 8 time library](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp).